# What is the key searching time for unordered map in C++ STL?

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, hashtable, unordered-map

I have some 2D arrays and there are some corresponding values for every 2D array . I am converting these 2D arrays into strings and then these strings have been used as 'keys' and the corresponding values of 2D arrays have been used as 'values' in an unordered map.

2D array to string conversion process (with an example) :

A[3][3] = {(1,2,3) , (4,5,6) , (7,8,9)}

Corresponding string will be : 1+2+3 * 4+5+6 * 7+8+9

So what will be the key searching time in the hash table which is internally used by unordered map ?

Answer (score 1):

If your key is a `std::string`, then there'll be some time complexity for hashing the string.  Microsoft's Visual C++ Standard Library does a very poor job of hashing, but does it in constant time O(1) (by only incorporating 10 characters evenly spaced along the string into the hash value).  GNU is the other extreme, using a very good hash function, and it'll be O(K) in the length of the key.

Then the hash table "key searching time" as you call it will be amortised O(1) with respect to the number of elements in the table, but if other strings have hashed to the same bucket they'll need to be compared: each of those comparisons will be O(1) if the lengths differ, or as much as O(K) if the key is found or matches an initial substringof an existing key.

This is all common sense really - where people get confused is in trying to give a single big-O value to the entire operation: well, it is O(K) in this case, as that's the worst complexity of any of the operations involved.